# Assign required file to global namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I need to assign included file in a function scope to global namespace.
Is there any possible way?

```
// global namespace

function scope()
{
 // function scope
 require_once 'file.php';
}
```

this will include file.php to function and can't access global variables.

Comment: namespace your_namespace; add this to your included file

Comment: @Osama thanks, so I should give a namespace to main file and call 'use namespace' in target file?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to cycle through all defined vars and reassign them to $GLOBALS

```php
function scope() {
  require_once 'file.php';
  foreach ( get_defined_vars() as $k => $v) {
    $GLOBALS[$k] = $v;
  }
}
```